# How to call a vuejs function in jquery if your using vue with export default

Tags: jquery, vue.js

On the vuejs.org website there is this function.
[image: vuejs function]
I want to replicate this to test some code i am writing in an on click function on a table row using jquery.

```
   $("#table1 tr").click(function () {
            // alert($(this).text());
            //  alert($(this).children("td").html());
            // app.greet();
        });
```

I want to call the vue function there but my vue code is written in the script and i am using export default like so.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {

        }
etc.
}
```

If i want to use this vue function in jquery how do i call it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to instantiate the App, then you can call the method on it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

const app = new Vue(App)

$("#table1 tr").click(function () {
  app.greet()
})
```

Comment: can i do this in separate components

Comment: also when you say import app from app.js do i import my app.vue file there or my main.js file.

Comment: @DanielM96 The `.vue` file. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  mounted(){
     $("#table1 tr").on('click',()=> {
        this.greet()
     });
  },

  methods:{
    greet(){
      console.log('greet method')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.