# Call a VueJS Method using jQuery

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I've run into an issue with an existing design I am adding VueJS too. They are deadset on using jQuery based datatables, so I am forced to call my VueJS method using jQuery.

What command would I use to call the method `openModal()`?

This is what I have so far, which regrettably, isn't working.

```
$(".flagBtn").click(function() {
    Vue.openModal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the App, then you can call the method on it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

const app = new Vue(App)

$(".flagBtn").click(function() {
     app.openModal()
});
```

This answer has been taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783752/7085305)

Comment: `app.openModal()`